# why are some properties of lazarus highlighted red

Tags: forms, user-interface, properties, lazarus, freepascal

[image: lazarus properties box]

Why is this property red. What does it signify. Some properties cannot be set to anything that does not result in red writing. There is nothing in the documentation to help.A google search of the word red and any combination of other words does not produce meaningful results.

Answer (score 4):

These are the properties whose values are different from the default values.